# if-statements in Google docs all fail, no matter how easy

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-docs

Reading the documentation, I'm led to believe Google Docs should be able to handle if-statements in the following format (straight from the documentation):

```
IF(test, then_value, otherwise_value)
```

So, as a test, I try the following:

```
=IF(2>1, 2, 1)
```

This should obviously print `2` since two will always be greater than one. However, this throws me an error. So, I try the following instead:

```
=IF(1=1, 1, 1)
```

This also gives me an error.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, unless Google stopped supporting if-statements in their docs. Can anyone help?

Comment: It works on my google docs with `,` as well as `;`. please post your error message

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/VGt82eG.png (it says "processing error") -- this is when trying `=IF(2>1, 2, 1)` specifically

Comment: This may be a language specific problem. I tried it on old doc as well as new one with out any issues. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has obviously changed this without changing the [proper documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&hlrm=sv&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240291). According to the documentation, as of writing this, the correct way to do this is as in my question:

```
=IF(2>1, 2, 1)
```

However, if you start writing "=IF" in Google Drive, a popup guides you in the correct direction, and it seems they have changed the syntax to:

```
=IF(2>1; 2; 1)
```

Note the use of semicolons instead of commas. That's it.

Comment: As with excel whether commas or semi-colons are used depends on your `regional settings`, e.g. US and UK would typically use commas, continental European settings would be semi-colons - what are your regional settings -if Swedish then, yes, semi-colons would be default separators?

Comment: I still think it's strange that this isn't pointed out in the documentation (not necessarily "the way it is in language x specifically" but the fact that it differs by region).